# How to copy files from windows to mac in mono?

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, mono

As the title says, I want copy files from windows to mac in mono. Here is my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace CopyFiles
{
    public class EmptyClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string windowsPath = "\\\\another-machine-name\\Share\\Tem";
            string macPath = "..";
            CopyFiles (windowsPath, macPath);
        }

        public static bool CopyFiles(string oldPath, string newPath)
        {

            Directory.CreateDirectory (newPath); 
            if (!Directory.Exists (oldPath)) { 
                return false;
            }

            string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories (oldPath);
            if (directories.Length > 0) { 
                foreach (string   d   in   directories) { 
                    CopyFiles (d, newPath + d.Substring (d.LastIndexOf ("\\")));
                } 
            } 

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles (oldPath);
            if (files.Length > 0) { 
                foreach (string   s   in   files) { 
                    File.Copy (s, newPath + s.Substring (s.LastIndexOf ("\\"))); 
                } 
            } 
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The `winowsPath` is a shared path. I don't know how to write a mac path.
Is there anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the code will be running on the OS X side.

OS X has a single root node for the file system `/`.  Everything else comes under that root node.  For example, a `document.doc` in your home folder would be referred like `/Users/Long/document.doc`.

If you are unsure of where a file is located then you can follow these steps to find out:

- Locate the container folder in Finder
- Open a new terminal window

  - Type <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>{space}</kbd>
- Drag the folder from Finder into terminal
- Press <kbd>{return}</kbd>
- Type <kbd>p</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>{return}</kbd>

This will change the current working directory to the one you drug into finder, then pwd will print the working directory out (on screen) so you can see what the path should look like.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you said, I drag my share folder into terminal, get the path `/Volumes/Share/Tem`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you said, After I drag my share folder into terminal, I get the path `/Volumes/Share/Tem`. Then i change the `windowsPath` to `/Volumes/Share/Tem`, and change the `macPath` to `/Users/Long/Desktop/TestFolder`. It works. The `Tem` folder ware copied from windows to Mac... but I don't know what's the mean of the '/volumes'.

Comment: `/Volumes` is where the various hdd, sdd, and smb (etc..) drives are mounted in the file system.